# Linux Kernel configs official documentation

Tags: linux, configuration, linux-kernel, kernel

When compiling a linux kernel, one of the first step is to generate the `.config` file which in my case I'm getting from the currently installed kernel. So it generates this files with a lot of KEY=VALUES like:

```
CONFIG_64BIT=y
CONFIG_X86_64=y
CONFIG_X86=y
CONFIG_INSTRUCTION_DECODER=y
CONFIG_OUTPUT_FORMAT="elf64-x86-64"
CONFIG_ARCH_DEFCONFIG="arch/x86/configs/x86_64_defconfig"
CONFIG_STACKTRACE_SUPPORT=y
# etc...
```

I can just copy/paste one of those keys in google and I'll probably find (in some random site) a detailed explanation for what it is used for. So my question is, is there an official place where I can rely to know about those configs? I searched on kernel.org/doc and didn't found so I decided to ask here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation can be access through the `make menuconfig`, each entry is documented (a paragraph describes the option).

But you can only see the options that are available to your architecture, and also if you disable a feature it may hide some related option.

If you want to see all options, the best thing it is to open the Kconfig files.
You can go here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/ and search for Kconfig files (There are at this moment 1021 Kconfig files)

But clearly if you do not know where to search, for example if you are looking for `CONFIG_INSTRUCTION_DECODER`, from the kernel source tree run: `grep INSTRUCTION_DECODER $(find -name Kconfig)`

But `INSTRUCTION_DECODER` is not really a good example since there is no associated help section with that option...